# "heroku git:clone -a myapp" results in "`git:clone` is not a heroku command."

Tags: git, heroku

I was using `heroku git:clone -a myapp` to clone my app successfully from heroku over the past 6 months while developing. But since today this command results in `"git:clone" is not a heroku command.`

Did they change something?

I also updated to the latest heroku-toolbelt version, but still same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely the heroku-git plugin was suddenly missing.

I manually reinstalled heroku-git: `heroku plugins:install heroku-git`

now its working again.